# When do I need to use parameterized type in method definition?

Tags: methods, types, julia

1. Is there a difference if I define a function with or without the type parameters?

```
foo(v::Vector) = sum(v)
```

versus

```
foo(v::Vector{T}) where {T} = sum(v)
```

2. Is the benefit of including the parameters the ability to reference the type itself?

Example of what I mean by referencing the type:

```
bar(v::Vector{T}) where {T} = zeros(T,length(v))
```

Comment: You are right. A common case of using templates is when you want to dispatch based on the eltype: `foo(v::Vector{T}) where {T <: Number} = sum(v)` would work, but `foo(v <: Vector{Number}) = sum(v)` would not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `foo(v::Vector) = sum(v)` and `foo(v) = sum(v)` compile to the same JIT code when v is a Vector.
2. Your example's `where {T}` does nothing unless T is referenced in the function body, as in your `zeros(T, length(v))` example. You could, however, use that syntax to restrict T's type with that part of the function declaration, for example with `where T isa Number`.